# How to query roundable amount?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with 4 records as below

```
123.15
122.3
91273.77
1.12
```

How to write a query that can return me rows with roundable nearest 5 cents? Which should return me row 3 and row 4?

row 1 and row 2 are not selected because they are already rounded, row 3 and row 4 are selected because they are not rounded yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. In `WHERE` clause just multiply the value with 100 and do modulo division with 10. If the reminder is 0 or 5, assume it has been already rounded. Select the rest.

**Query**

```
select [column_value]
from [your_table_name]
where cast(([column_value] * 100) % 10  as int) not in (0, 5);
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/651238/how-to-query-roundable-amount)**